# Kaniko: How to cache folders from Gatsby build in Kubernetes using Tekton?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kaniko, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I am building a CI/CD pipeline using **Tekton** on a bare metal Kubernetes Cluster. I have managed to cache the necessary images (Node & Nginx) and the layers, but how can I cache the .cache / public folders created by **Gatsby build**? These folders are not present in the repo. If the build step does not find these folders in takes longer because it needs to create all images using Sharp.

The pipeline has a PVC attached. In the task it is called *source* (workspaces). To be more clear, how can I copy the Gatsby folders to this PVC after the build has finished and to the Kaniko container before the next build?

**The Tekton task has the following steps:**

1. Use Kaniko warmer to cache Docker Images used in the Docker build
2. Create a timestamp so that "RUN build" is executed every time even if the files don't change because it runs a GraphQL query
3. Build and push image using Kaniko
4. & 5. Export image digest used by next step in the pipeline

```yaml
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: build-docker-image
spec:
  params:
    - name: pathToDockerFile
      type: string
      description: The path to the dockerfile to build
      default: $(resources.inputs.source-repo.path)/Dockerfile
    - name: pathToContext
      type: string
      description: |
        The build context used by Kaniko
        (https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#kaniko-build-contexts)
      default: $(resources.inputs.source-repo.path)
  resources:
    inputs:
      - name: source-repo
        type: git
    outputs:
      - name: builtImage
        type: image
      - name: event-to-sink
        type: cloudEvent
  workspaces:
    # PVC
    - name: source
      description: |
        Folder to write docker image digest
  results:
    - name: IMAGE-DIGEST
      description: Digest of the image just built.
  steps:
    - name: kaniko-warmer
      image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/warmer
      workingDir: $(workspaces.source.path)
      args:
        - --cache-dir=$(workspaces.source.path)/cache
        - --image=node:14-alpine
        - --image=nginx:1.19.5
    - name: print-date-unix-timestamp
      image: bash:latest
      script: |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        date | tee $(params.pathToContext)/date
    - name: build-and-push
      workingDir: $(workspaces.source.path)
      image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.3.0
      env:
        - name: 'DOCKER_CONFIG'
          value: '/tekton/home/.docker/'
      command:
        - /kaniko/executor
      args:
        - --build-arg=CACHEBUST=$(params.pathToContext)/date
        - --dockerfile=$(params.pathToDockerFile)
        - --destination=$(resources.outputs.builtImage.url)
        - --context=$(params.pathToContext)
        - --cache=true
        - --cache-ttl=144h
        - --cache-dir=$(workspaces.source.path)/cache
        - --use-new-run
        - --snapshotMode=redo
        - --cache-repo=<repo>/kaniko-cache
        - --log-timestamp
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
    - name: write-digest
      workingDir: $(workspaces.source.path)
      image: gcr.io/tekton-releases/github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/cmd/imagedigestexporter:v0.16.2
      command: ['/ko-app/imagedigestexporter']
      args:
        - -images=[{"name":"$(resources.outputs.builtImage.url)","type":"image","url":"$(resources.outputs.builtImage.url)","digest":"","OutputImageDir":"$(workspaces.source.path)/$(params.pathToContext)/image-digest"}]
        - -terminationMessagePath=$(params.pathToContext)/image-digested
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
    - name: digest-to-result
      workingDir: $(workspaces.source.path)
      image: docker.io/stedolan/jq@sha256:a61ed0bca213081b64be94c5e1b402ea58bc549f457c2682a86704dd55231e09
      script: |
        cat $(params.pathToContext)/image-digested | jq '.[0].value' -rj | tee /$(results.IMAGE-DIGEST.path)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine as build
ARG CACHEBUST=1

RUN apk update \
  && apk add \
  build-base \
  libtool \
  autoconf \
  automake \
  pkgconfig \
  nasm \
  yarn \
  libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev giflib-dev tiff-dev \
  zlib-dev \
  python \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

EXPOSE 8000 9000

RUN yarn global add gatsby-cli

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./package.json .
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN yarn build && echo $CACHEBUST

CMD ["yarn", "serve"]

FROM nginx:1.19.5 as serve
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/public /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I cache the .cache / public folders created by Gatsby build? These folders are not present in the repo.

If Persistent Volumes is available on your cluster and these volumes is available from all nodes, you can use a PVC-backed workspace for cache.

A more generic solution that also works in a regional cluster (e.g. cloud) is to upload the cached folder to something, e.g. a Bucket ([Minio](https://min.io/)?) or potentially Redis? Then also need a Task that download this folder - potentially in parallel with `git clone` when starting a new `PipelineRun`. GitHub Actions has a similar solution with the [cache action](https://github.com/actions/cache).

Example of a Task with two workspaces that copy a file from one workspace to the other:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1  
kind: Task  
metadata:   
  name: copy-between-workspaces 
spec:   
  workspaces:   
    - name: ws-a    
    - name: ws-b    
  steps:    
    - name: copy
      image: ubuntu 
      script: cp $(workspaces.ws-a.path)/myfile $(workspaces.ws-b.path)/myfile
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! There is a PVC attached to the pipeline. In the task the workspaces is called source. How can I can copy the the Gatsby folders to this PVC after the build has finished and copy it to the step before the next build? I changed my question to reflect this.

Comment: There are two alternatives; either upload the files to e.g. Redis or a bucket. Or use an additional workspace PVC for cached data. So you need a task to copy the files to the other workspace e.g. `cp cache/ $(workspace.cache).path` or someting.

Comment: @EspenFinnesand I added an example of a copy-task - haven't tested it but I think it should work.

Comment: @EspenFinnesand to get this working with two PVCs, you probably has to disable the affinity-assistant in the configmap as well.

Comment: I still struggle with how to export the build folders from Kaniko. I can use workspaces to input the folders to Kaniko via --context. Thought export might work with --tarPath but that did not work either. Can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: Ah, you want to cache when you are building in a multi-stage dockerImage. Unless you can use https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/master/README.md#caching otherwise it might work if you build in separate Tekton Tasks before building image? that might help with custom caching, perhaps?

Comment: Yes. I managed to setup the Kaniko cache both for caching layers and caching base images. But I want to cache even more. I want to cache certain folders created during Docker **RUN npm run build**. Using your task I am able to input already cached folders into Kaniko. Thought it might be possible to extract them aswell. But using an extra task (i.e. Node) in the pipeline to build and export those folders is a good solution. Thanks a lot for your help!